# I don't know how to add these features to the site

Tags: html, css, authentication, header, searchbar

I need to add 3 buttons to my header
1 - a search bar
2 simple button in the form of text Enter and
3 is a picture of a bag with the number 0

yes i know for a pro in html the question will sound stupid but i am newbie and i need to add this to my header in its free part,I have never made this type of button in the header and you will probably find a lot of mistakes in my code.

yes, I know what you will say "there is no one here who will not write the code for you", but I have never hidden even with the search bar, and I have also never made a login button with an icon in front of it, and I lack the experience to do it

[image]

my site code -
html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    color:green;
  }

  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:green;
    
  }

  .logo::before {
   
    content:url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 3px;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: center;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  logo:before {
      content:url(images/quotemarks.png);
  }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any svg icon one of the free icon services is [ion icons](https://ionic.io/ionicons)
You can insert icons like this

```css
.icons{
width:100vw;
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-end;
align-items:center;
gap:15px;
}

ion-icon{
font-size:30px;
color:green;
}
ion-icon:last-child{
margin-right:50px;
}
input{
outline:none;
border:none;
}
input::placeholder{
font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="icons">
<input placeholder="Search.." type="text">
<ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="bag-handle-outline"></ion-icon>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I read the documentation but I did not understand whether I can add text before the icon or search bar before the magnifying glass

Comment: you can add text normally inside the `p` tag before the icon

Comment: When I do this, the text moves below the icon

Comment: @GarfildRaven Now you can check the updated answer it solves your problem

Comment: thank you very much, I wouldn't have done it myself even on Sunday, but could you also add a search bar next to the magnifying glass

Comment: yeah I can add but can you please accept that answer if it solved the problem

Comment: @GarfildRaven I have added the Search Bar

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have problems adding your code to the site (the code of my site is in question), can you help and put your code there?

Comment: have you added the script tags without which icons won't work

Comment: should they be added to the header? if so, even if I add the code (script) to the header and they do not appear

Comment: your code is written using floats I don't have much experience can I modify your code using flexbox ?

Comment: so of course you can modify it

Comment: managed to modify?

Comment: yess https://codepen.io/shivam90727/pen/WNyvywZ done without changing float layout

Comment: so finally ( ͡❛͜ʖ ͡❛)

Comment: Could you help me with my new question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74239921/how-to-make-fixed-text-and-button-on-slider