# How to make fixed text and button on slider?

Tags: html, css, image, button, slider

I'm new to programming and I need to add a slider right under the header, you'll probably think "well, a slider and a slider, why can't you add it?" but it's not a simple slider here. 1 I have never worked with sliders
2 as you know usually if there is text on the slider then when you flip the picture it changes or moves But in this slider the text is static and when you flip the picture it not only does not change but also does not move the same applies to the button under it

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
  }
  
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
   
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    color:green;
  }

  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:green;
    
  }

  .logo::before {
   
    content:url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 3px;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  
.icons{
/*   display:block; */
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
  float:right;
  padding:16px;
  margin-right:50px;
  
/*   clear:both; */
  
}
ion-icon{
  font-size:25px;
}

.search{
  border:none;
}
.search::placeholder{
  font-size
}


  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: center;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  logo:before {
      content:url(images/quotemarks.png);
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
  <header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <div class="icons">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">
<ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
      
<ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="bag-handle-outline"></ion-icon>
</div>
  </ul>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

professionals in html & css will think that this is a stupid question, but I have never done such a thing and I did not find an answer on the Internet (please forgive me for a possibly stupid question, I am a newbie)

Comment: Please show your problem in the run code snippet, now we can not see any problem.

Comment: @FarshadVaghari I have no problems with the code that I showed, my problem is that I do not know how to write such a slider

Comment: @FarshadVaghari ?

Answer (score -1):

This one is done with wrapping your  element with some  as .slide-wrapper and then put your ,

and  to another  called .slide-content. And now put this .slide-content child element in your parent element .slide-wrapper. Give slider-wrapper a position: relative; and .slide-content a position: absolute;

(thanks for the answer @m-naeem66622 - Answer - [how to add this on slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74247644/how-to-add-this-on-slider))

Comment: plzzz add some link of that some link to that question where it had been answered so that anyone could find it