# how to add this on slider?

Tags: html, css

Description of my problem: I have a slider without js and I need to add a fixed Text and a button on top of it

html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Shop</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
  <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
  <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <div class="icons">
<input class="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">
<ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
<ion-icon name="bag-handle-outline"></ion-icon>
</div>
  </ul>
</header>

<div class="slider">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
  <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3">
  
  <div class="switch">
    <label for="btn1"></label>
    <label for="btn2"></label>
    <label for="btn3"></label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="slider-inner">
    <div class="slides">
      <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.webp"/>
      <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.webp"/>
      <img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,fp_0.73_0.29,q_90/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.webp"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
 
  a {
    color: #000;
  }
  
  /* header */
  
  .header {
    background-color: #ffff;
    /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  
  .header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
   
  .header li a:hover,
  .header .menu-btn:hover {
    color:green;
  }

  
  .header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:green;
    
  }

  .logo::before {
   
    content:url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
            display: inline-block;
            padding-right: 3px;
            vertical-align: middle;
          }
  
  /* menu */
  
  .header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
  }
  
  
.icons{
/*   display:block; */
  display:flex;
  gap:20px;
  float:right;
  padding:16px;
  margin-right:50px;
  
/*   clear:both; */
  
}
ion-icon{
  font-size:25px;
}

.search{
  border:none;
}
.search::placeholder{
  font-size
}


  /* menu icon */
  
  .header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
  }
  
  /* menu btn */
  
  .header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu {
    max-height: 240px;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
  .header .menu-btn:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
  }
  
  /* 48em = 768px */
  
  @media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
      float: left;
    }
    .header li a {
      padding: 20px 30px;
    }
    .header .menu {
      clear: none;
      float: center;
      max-height: none;
    }
    .header .menu-icon {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 680px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  transform: translateY(40%);
}

.slider input[name="switch"] {
  display: none;
}

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -40px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.switch label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #2f363c;
  background-color: #738290;
}

#btn1:checked~.switch label[for="btn1"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn2:checked~.switch label[for="btn2"] {
  background-color: white;
}

#btn3:checked~.switch label[for="btn3"] {
  background-color: white;
}

.slider-inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.slides img {
  width: 680px;
  height: 340px;
  float: left;
}

#btn1:checked~slider-inner slides {
  transform: translate(0);
}

#btn2:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-680px);
}

#btn3:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
  transform: translate(-1360px);
}
```

also, this slider is written only in html and css, so there may be many bugs here, and the code itself is probably written quite poorly and I have never made sliders so I don't know how to do it can you help?

[image]

this is what the slider should look like

Comment: Check the answer below and take the code from the code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is done with following steps:

- Remove the `<img>` tags in `div.slides`
- Create `<div>` with class `.slide-wrapper`
- Add `<h1>`, `<p>` and `<button>` in `div.slide-wrapper`
- Now add required image to the background of `div.slide-wrapper` using css `background-image: url(image-link);`
- Don't forget to give the `background-size: cover;` to the `div.slide-wrapper` to fit the image in `<div>`

It is just an easy task...

> Note: I am not going to style this one it is all up to you. Give the content some margin and padding freely to gain required design. You can also set image using before and after pseudo selectors.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

a {
    color: #000;
}

/* header */

.header {
    background-color: #ffff;
    /*box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}

.header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.header li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.header li a:hover,
.header .menu-btn:hover {
    color: green;
}


.header .logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;

    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;

}

.logo::before {

    content: url('imgonline-com-ua-Resize-HhpRdaDieHxuk8.png');
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* menu */

.header .menu {
    clear: both;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .2s ease-out;
}


.icons {
    /*   display:block; */
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    float: right;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-right: 50px;

    /*   clear:both; */

}

ion-icon {
    font-size: 25px;
}

.search {
    border: none;
}

.search::placeholder {
    /* font-size */
}


/* menu icon */

.header .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding: 28px 20px;
    position: relative;
    user-select: none;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon {
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .2s ease-out;
    width: 18px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before,
.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    background: #333;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all .2s ease-out;
    width: 100%;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:before {
    top: 5px;
}

.header .menu-icon .navicon:after {
    top: -5px;
}

/* menu btn */

.header .menu-btn {
    display: none;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu {
    max-height: 240px;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.header .menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
    top: 0;
}

/* 48em = 768px */

@media (min-width: 48em) {
    .header li {
        float: left;
    }

    .header li a {
        padding: 20px 30px;
    }

    .header .menu {
        clear: none;
        float: center;
        max-height: none;
    }

    .header .menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }
}

.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 680px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    transform: translateY(40%);
}

.slider input[name="switch"] {
    display: none;
}

.switch {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -40px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.switch label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #2f363c;
    background-color: #738290;
}

#btn1:checked~.switch label[for="btn1"] {
    background-color: white;
}

#btn2:checked~.switch label[for="btn2"] {
    background-color: white;
}

#btn3:checked~.switch label[for="btn3"] {
    background-color: white;
}

.slider-inner {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slides {
    width: 500%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    position: relative;
}

.slides .slide-wrapper {
    width: 680px;
    height: 340px;
    float: left;
}

#btn1:checked~slider-inner slides {
    transform: translate(0);
}

#btn2:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
    transform: translate(-680px);
}

#btn3:checked~.slider-inner .slides {
    transform: translate(-1360px);
}

/* Code For Your Question */

.slides .slide-wrapper {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slides .slide-wrapper:nth-child(1){
    background-image: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.webp');
}
.slides .slide-wrapper:nth-child(2){
    background-image: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.webp');
}
.slides .slide-wrapper:nth-child(3){
    background-image: url('https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,fp_0.73_0.29,q_90/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.webp');
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Shop</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <a href="" class="logo">Fresh market</a>
        <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#work">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Shop</a></li>
            <li><a href="#careers">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <div class="icons">
                <input class="search" placeholder="Search.." type="text">
                <ion-icon name="search-outline"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon name="person-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon name="bag-handle-outline"></ion-icon>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div class="slider">
        <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn2">
        <input type="radio" name="switch" id="btn3">

        <div class="switch">
            <label for="btn1"></label>
            <label for="btn2"></label>
            <label for="btn3"></label>
        </div>

        <div class="slider-inner">
            <div class="slides">
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                    <h1>Fresh Market</h1>
                    <p>We'll Deliver Everything You Need</p>
                    <button>Shop Online</button>
                </div>
                <!-- <img
                        src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_f2ae964f4e3d4bb8af8b6cdda0ad86bd~mv2.webp" /> -->
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                    <h1>Fresh Market 2</h1>
                    <p>We'll Deliver Everything You Need</p>
                    <button>Shop Online</button>
                </div>
                <!-- <img
                        src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,q_90/ad420a_d2d8311f21fe4d7bb4836f82c5011a46~mv2.webp" /> -->
                <div class="slide-wrapper">
                    <h1>Fresh Market 3</h1>
                    <p>We'll Deliver Everything You Need</p>
                    <button>Shop Online</button>
                    <!-- <img
                        src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_1112,h_601,fp_0.73_0.29,q_90/ad420a_01886647b6df44198b05bc86420472c0~mv2.webp" /> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much, and I will try to make the styles myself

Comment: it has some error sorry i will fix it just give me moment the text and button doesnt appear on second and third slide

Comment: @GarfildRaven Just stick to the answer i will be rightt back

Comment: oh ok i will wait

Comment: happened fix bug?

Comment: @GarfildRaven updated answer check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249157/discussion-between-m-naeem66622-and-garfild-raven).